# Changing Windows Universal App LockScreen Background

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, win-universal-app, lockscreen

`Windows.System.UserProfile.Lockscreen` is not available in the WinRT API for Windows Phone.  Is it possible to programatically modify the lockscreen background of a windows phone device from a winrt app by some other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. LockScreen providers are in the list of [Windows Phone 8 features for which there is no Windows Phone Store equivalent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn642486(v=vs.105).aspx). They are available only to Silverlight apps.